# Is there a way to use >, = or in a C# switch? I'm looking for ways to tidy a small section of code

Tags: c#

Here's the code that I have:

```
if (spc > 1)
{
   if (shpc == 0)
      return "You have " + spc.ToString() + " visible cards in your card deck. ";
   if (shpc == 1)
      return "You have " + vc.ToString() + " visible and 1 hidden card in your deck. ";
    return "You have " + vc.ToString() + " visible and " + shpc.ToString() + " hidden cards in your deck. ";
 }
 return null;
```

Does anyone know of a way I can code this with a switch or another way I could tidy the code?

Comment: switch was given support for pattern matching a few versions ago: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#using-pattern-matching-switch-statements | That being said it is expanded in 8.0, so some things might have been missing the first itteration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#more-patterns-in-more-places

Comment: String interpolation would clean up a lot of that string stuff.

Comment: There's a nuget package for pluralization, try Humanizer or Pluralize.NET. e.g. `pluralizer.Format(5, "dog"); // => "dogs"`

Comment: You can start by eliminating the `ToString` calls. `ToString` is called automatically by string concatenation.

Comment: In your code, is `spc` used two times instead of `vc`? Also, if "visible cards" is not contracted to "visible and ... card(s)" you could make shorter code. But it would be also very difficult to localize to another language. Which it already is difficult with those partial strings, so I guess you don't care about that.

Comment: I too am confused by the fact that the code seems to shift from using `spc` to using `vc`; is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why polluting some easy to read code by some fancy syntax? But if you really want, you may use a chained ternary operator.

```
if (spc > 1)
{
    return 
        shcp == 0 ? "You have " + spc.ToString() + " visible cards in your card deck. " :
        shpc == 1 ? "You have " + vc.ToString() + " visible and 1 hidden card in your deck. " :
                    "You have " + vc.ToString() + " visible and " + shpc.ToString() + " hidden cards in your deck. ";
 }
 return null;
```

You can further delete all those `ToString`-calls, as they are implictely added anyway when concatenating strings and objects.

Comment: And remove `.ToString()`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it would make it tidier; switch statements are pretty ugly. But if you really want to, you could do something like this:

```
string Output = null;
switch(shpc)
{
    case 0: Output = $"You have {spc} visible cards in your card deck."; break;
    case 1: Output = $"You have {vc} visible and 1 hidden card in your deck."; break;
    default: Output = $"You have {vc} visible and {shpc} hidden cards in your deck."; break;
}
return Output;
```

EDIT.
As suggested by Franck in the comments, `case 1` could be omitted in favor of a smarter `default` case:

```
$"You have {vc} visible and {shpc} hidden card{(shpc > 1? "s":"")} in your deck."
```

You could also omit the `Output` variable and return from the `switch` directly. None of this things would make it clearer IMO, so I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Case 1 can be omitted. Just keep default instead and add an "s" to card when > 1

Comment: The first `if` statement is checking a variable named `spc`, while the others are checking a variable named `shpc`

Comment: @Franck Why can case 1 be omitted?

Comment: @MarianoLuisVilla Since `shpc` is 1 the results of `case 1` will be the same as the result of `default`.  However `case 1` was suppose to have "card" instead of "cards".  However "cards" seems like the more proper usage unless `vc` is 0.

Comment: Would  it not be possible to have return in the switch instead of Output =  ?

Comment: @MarianoLuisVilla what i meant is this cover case 1 and default `$"You have {vc} visible and {shpc} hidden card{(shpc > 1? "s":"")} in your deck."`

Comment: @Franck Oh, got you. IMO, that would make it harder to read, but let's add it to have the option posted.

Comment: Will you ever want to translate this game into another language? Perhaps an i18n framework should be handling most/all of this

Answer (score 2):

This is an opportunity to step back and refactor.  What's the problem?  Pluralization is the problem, so start with that.

```
private static string[] words = {"no", "one", "two", "three" };
public static string Pluralize(this string t, int q)
{
  string s = q == 1 ? "" : "s";
  string n = q < words.Length ? words[q] : q.ToString();
  return n + " " + t + s;
}
```

Can you see how you can use this to make your code look more like its meaning?

Comment: But this assumes OP may change the output in a way such as "you have one ... and no ...".

Comment: @HimBromBeere still it's a good example for pluralization for english strings (can only speak for english and french and i know it cannot work for french)

Comment: @HimBromBeere: The point is not the specifics of the solution. The point of the answer is to encourage the original poster to step back and reconsider; when your code is a mess, that's an opportunity to think about whether there is some simplifying, reusable abstraction that would clean it up, rather than just rearranging the mess into a slightly different mess.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `spc` and `vc` are the same thing (you forgot to clean the code up for us) this is the holy grail that you asked for, which I however don't particularly like. Full localizable sentences are preferred in my world.

```
if (vc > 0)
    return $"You have {vc} visible {shpc > 0 ? $"and {shpc} hidden " : ""}card{vc > 1 && shpc == 0 || shpc > 1 ? "s" : ""} in your deck. ";
```

Comment: It's shorter, sure, but is it "cleaned up" / more readable? :) Feels almost like this question will turn into golf

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
if(shpc < 2)
  return null;

if (vc == 0 && hc == 0)
  return "You have no cards in your deck"
if (vc == 0)
  return $"You have {hc} hidden card{S(hc)} in your deck";
if (hc == 0)
  return $"You have {vc} visible card{S(vc)} in your deck";

return $"You have {vc} visible and {hc} hidden card{S(hc}} in your deck";



//a cheapo pluralize method. 
private string S(int i){
  return i == 1 ? "": "s";
}
```

I've always preferred things that format string to be as readable (fewest string concats) as possible. Feel free to chop some of these out if for example you can never have an empty deck or a deck that has only hidden cards ; not sure what the rules of this game are

If you invert the logic of your if(shpc) you can avoid nesting. I've used another variable `hc` for the count of hidden cards - I couldn't work out if this was `shpc` or not, and there was a bit of confusion over consistency of spc/shpc/vc?

If you ever plan on translating your game into another language, don't do any of this. Take a look at something like i18next instead

Perhaps see also [Clever way to append 's' for plural form in .Net (syntactic sugar)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875312/clever-way-to-append-s-for-plural-form-in-net-syntactic-sugar)

Answer (score 1):

This is a refactoring of your code using C# 6.0 string interpolation, C# 7.0 pattern matching and a C# 8.0 switch expression which answers your (purely syntactical) question. There are lots of other ways of doing it, I'm just giving a hint what's *possible* with modern C# language features. Whether it actually makes sense, depends on your business context. At the very least, the more concise syntax makes it easier to spot any logical problems; e.g. is it correct that you sometimes use `spc` and at other times `vc` to indicate the number of visible cards?

```
return shpc switch{
    _ when spc <= 1 => null,
    0 => $"You have {spc} visible cards in your card deck. ",
    1 => $"You have {vc} visible and one hidden card in your deck. ",
    _ => $"You have {vc} visible and {shpc} hidden cards in your deck. "
};
```